# Can PowerBi dynamically load files?

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, power-platform

I think I'm on a severe wishful thinking trip here, please confirm if I am, if not then what would be the process to accomplish this?

Every day a team compiles an Excel file and sends it via email attachment. I have a Power Automate Flow that saves the attachment into a SharePoint space.

I can create a Power Bi and manually connect load those files to create the report, but it seems the real "Power" would be to not have to manually connect the new file (which has the creation date in the filename - eg 'Daily DRR 3-16-22.xlsx') every day, ergo:

What steps (using the Power Platform) would I take to have my PowerBi report auto (dynamically) refresh using the last 5 files (days) in the SharePoint drive? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Customize the query that gets the underlying data to load the files dynamically (`SharePoint.Files`) rather than by a fixed name. PowerQuery M is a full-fledged programming language (though heavily specialized towards data transformation, obviously).

Comment: Thanks for this pointer!!! Started the new scripting.